# Manipulate: The animation disappears as soon as I start it, why? And even if I try to fix it "manually", Manipulate shows the wrong animation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, manipulate

Code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

L0 = 2;
ω = 4;
L[t_] = L0 + δ *Sin[ω*t + Pi];
x[t_] = L[t]*Cos[α[t]];
y[t_] = L[t]*Sin[α[t]];
T = m/2 * ((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2);
U = -m*g*x[t];
Lagr = T - U;
Lgr = Simplify[Expand[Lagr]];
Eq1 = D[#1, #2] - D[D[#1, #3], t] & [Lgr, α[t], α'[t]];
Eq2 = Solve[Eq1 == 0, α''[t]];
Equ = Eq1 /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2);
Lu[t_] = L[t] /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2);


f[p_, αmax_, Ω_, ε_,m_] := Module[{sol1},sol1 =NDSolve[{Equ ==  0, α[0] == αmax, α'[0] == 0}, α[t], {t, p, p - 1}, MaxSteps -> 100000];

Show[Graphics[{Black, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{Lu[p]*Sin[sol1[p][[1]]],-Lu[p]*Cos[sol1[p][[1]]]   }]}, Axes -> True],PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}]];

Manipulate[ f[p, αmax, Ω, ε, m], {{αmax,  1}, 1, 10}, {{Ω, 1}, 1, 6.5}, {{ε, 0.05}, 0.05, 0.5},{{m,1},1,10}, {{p, 0, "animation"},  0, Infinity, ControlType -> Trigger}]
```

It does show a ball at the very beginning of the animation, so it does plot something. But as soon as I click on the animation, the ball vanishes, and I am only left with an empty coordinate system.

**EDIT**

The fix here was not to use Lu inside of the Module. But I still get a wrong animation!

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

L0 = 2;
ω = 4;
L[t_] = L0 + δ *Sin[ω*t + Pi];
x[t_] = L[t]*Cos[α[t]];
y[t_] = L[t]*Sin[α[t]];
T = m/2 * ((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2);
U = -m*g*x[t];
Lagr = T - U;
Lgr = Simplify[Expand[Lagr]];
Eq1 = D[#1, #2] - D[D[#1, #3], t] & [Lgr, α[t], α'[t]];
Eq2 = Solve[Eq1 == 0, α''[t]];
Equ = Eq1 /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2);
Lu[t_] = L[t] /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2);

f[p_, αmax_, Ω_, ε_,m_] := Module[{sol1},sol1 =NDSolve[{Equ ==  0, α[0] == αmax, α'[0] == 0}, α[t], {t, p, p - 1}, MaxSteps -> 100000];Show[Graphics[{Black, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{( L[p] /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2))*Sin[sol1[p][[1]]],-( L[p] /. g -> L0*Ω^2 /. δ -> (ε * L0)/(Ω^2))*Cos[sol1[p][[1]]]   }]}, Axes -> True],PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}]];



Manipulate[ f[p, αmax, Ω, ε, m], {{αmax,  1}, 0, 10}, {{Ω, 1}, 0, 6.5}, {{ε, 0.05}, 0.05, 0.5},{{m,1},1,10}, {{p, 0, "animation"},  0, Infinity, ControlType -> Trigger}]
```

It should show a pendulum which starts moving slowly but once it gains momentum, it goes faster and faster. But instead, it shows me how a point is moving around a ball of radius 2!

Comment: **It does show a ball at the very beginning of the animation** no it does not. You have errors. You get this ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAzFk.png)  and if you click on the red ... dots it says `NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`  So your NDSolve did not work., You need to make all the functions you are using work OK before using Manipulate. You can test them each on their own using dummy input.

Comment: That's very strange, because I dummy tested it and the NDSolve worked fine.

Comment: it could be a version number issue? I am using 13.1. [Here it the notebook](https://12000.org/tmp/nov_11_2022/)  so you can see for yourself.

Comment: @Nasser I think I got it now, the error here was the function "Lu" which simply doesn't seem to work inside of this Module. So I basically wrote how I define Lu instead of Lu itself, and it worked. ALTHOUGH: it still shows a wrong (!) animation (it shouldn't be a point rotating around a ball of radius 2, it should actually be an animation of a pendulum which slowly starts to gain momentum and is moving faster and faster...). So, for some reason, although I get the animation going, I still get the WRONG animation, which should be impossible as I've used the correct Lagrangian and such

Comment: @Nasser I've edited the question so you can see the new code

Comment: your new code gives same error. `NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.` btw, it is confusing to have 2 sets of code. No need to keep the old one. Just keep the current one only.

Comment: @Nasser But I don't understand how it can give the same error message, if it DOES animate something ultimately? That's strange. I am using the browser version of Mathematica, so I can't open nb files at all in the first place. I don't know what version you're using.

Comment: **I don't know what version you're using** I mentioned that in the earlier comment.  I using V 13.1 on windows 10 desktop. I do not knjow anything about the browser version of Mathematica. May be that is the reason I see the error and you do not. May be someone else can figure out why. good luck.

Comment: @Nasser I've dummy tested it (code: Equ1 = Equ /. \[CapitalOmega] -> 1 /. \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 1 /. m->1;
sol1 =NDSolve[{Equ1 ==  0, \[Alpha][0] == 1, \[Alpha]'[0] == 0}, \[Alpha][
  t], {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 100000]) and it's fine, so there is no error message.